# Kronecker Product of Normal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, kronecker-product

> **Theorem.** If $A\in M_m$ and $B\in M_n$ are both normal, so is $A\otimes B$. The converse is true if $A\otimes B\ne 0$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $A\in M_m$ and $B\in M_n$ are both normal. Then
\begin{align*}
    (A\otimes B)^*(A\otimes B)=(A^*\otimes B^*)(A\otimes B)&=(A^*A)\otimes(B^*B) \\
&=(AA^*)\otimes(BB^*) \\
&=(A\otimes B)(A^*\otimes B^*)=(A\otimes B)(A\otimes B)^*. 
\end{align*}
Therefore, $A\otimes B$ is normal.

Now suppose that $A\otimes B$ is nonzero and normal. Then both $A$ and $B$ are nonzero. Then we have
\begin{equation*}
    (A^*A)\otimes(B^*B)=(AA^*)\otimes(BB^*). 
\end{equation*}
Consider the $i$-th diagonal block of these two products:
\begin{equation*}
    (A^*A)_{ii}(B^*B)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{ji}|^2}\right)(B^*B)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{ij}|^2}\right)(BB^*)=(AA^*)_{ii}(BB^*). 
\end{equation*}
Summing over all $i$'s, we can get
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{ji}|^2}\right)(B^*B)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|a_{ij}|^2}\right)(BB^*)}, 
\end{equation*}
That is, $$\operatorname{tr}(A^*A)\cdot(B^*B)=\operatorname{tr}(AA^*)\cdot(BB^*).$$ Since $A$ is nonzero, $\operatorname{tr}(A^*A)=\operatorname{tr}(AA^*)\ne 0$, which implies that $B^*B=BB^*$ and hence $A^*A=AA^*$. $\blacksquare$

---

Can anyone please help to check if my proof is valid? For the converse part, I am not confident whether such method indeed works. **Besides, if you have any alternative elegant proofs for this theorem, I would be extraordinarily happy to hear from you!**

Comment: +1. Your proof looks good to me. I particularly like your elegant use of matrix trace.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you! This argument was actually inspired by the hint from Horn & Johnson, *Topics in Matrix Analysis*. At the beginning I tried different equivalent criterion for normal matrices but none of them looked trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: in what follows, eigenvalues and singular values are always assumed to be sorted by modulus, i.e. $\sigma_k\geq \sigma_{k+1}$ and $\big\vert\lambda_k\big\vert\geq \big\vert \lambda_{k+1}\big \vert$

The key fact is that that
$\sum_{k=1}^m \sigma_k^{(C)}\gt \sum_{k=1}^m \vert\lambda_k^{(C)}\vert $
if $C$ is not normal.  (Conversely, of course, if $C$ is normal we have $\sigma_k^{(C)} =\vert\lambda_k^{(C)}\vert $ for all $k$.)

Using the above relationship we compare the singular values with (the modulus of) the eigenvalues of $A\otimes B$
noting that neither matrix is zero so e.g. their nuclear norms (Schatten 1-norms) are non-zero
$\sum_{k=1}^{m\cdot n}\sigma_{A\otimes B}$
$= \Big(\sum_{k=1}^m \sigma_k^{(A)}\big)\big(\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{j}^{(B)}\Big)$
$\geq \Big(\sum_{k=1}^m \big\vert \lambda_k^{(A)}\big\vert\Big)\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n \big\vert \lambda_{j}^{(B)}\big\vert\Big)$
$= \sum_{k=1}^{m\cdot n}\big\vert\lambda_{A\otimes B}\big\vert = \sum_{k=1}^{m\cdot n}\sigma_{A\otimes B}\gt 0$

where the final equality follows because $A\otimes B$ is normal.  The inequality is met with equality, thus $A$ is normal and $B$ is normal.

**deferred proof of the singular value inequality**
Using Schur Triangularization we can map $C$ to an upper triangular matrix $T$ with eigenvalues on the diagonal ordered from largest modulus to smallest.  Unitary multiplications don't change singular values so $T$ has the same singular values as $C$. Suppose that $C\in GL_m(\mathbb C)$. Further consider $T':=DT$ where $D$ is a unitary diagonal matrix chosen so that $T'$ has positive values on its diagonal.

Since it is invertible, the Polar Decomposition $T'=UP$ is unique.  If $U$ and $P$ are simultaneously diagonalizable then $T'$ is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix so $T'$ is normal which implies $T'$ is diagonal and hence $T$ is diagonal, i.e. $C$ is normal.

Now suppose $U$ and $P$ are not simultaneously diagonalizable:
$0\lt \sum_{k=1}^m\vert \lambda_k\vert = \text{trace}\big(T'\big)= \text{trace}\big(UP\big)= \text{trace}\big(U(V\Sigma V^H)\big)= \text{trace}\big((V^HUV)\Sigma\big)$
$= \text{trace}\big(Q\Sigma\big)=\sum_{k=1}^m q_{k,k}\cdot \sigma_k=\big\vert\sum_{k=1}^m q_{k,k}\cdot \sigma_k\big \vert$
$\leq \sum_{k=1}^m \big\vert q_{k,k}\big \vert \cdot \sigma_k $
$\lt \sum_{k=1}^m \sigma_k$

where the inequalities are triangle inequality, and the fact that $Q$ is a unitary non-diagonal matrix, hence it has at least one diagonal component with modulus $\lt 1$ and each $\sigma_k\gt 0$

*singular case:*
Now suppose $C$ has $M \in\big\{1,2,..,m-1\big\}$ non-zero eigenvalues.  (The nilpotent $C$ case is obvious.)
$S^{-1}US = S^H CS= \begin{bmatrix}
T_{M} &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0& N
\end{bmatrix} $  where $N$ is strictly upper triangular.

As before in the non-singular case we can left multiply by a diagonal unitary matrix such that the result is $ \begin{bmatrix}
T_{M}' &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0&  N
\end{bmatrix}$
where $T_{M}'$ is an upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal.  This new matrix has the same singular values as before.  Then
$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \vert \lambda_k^{(C)}\vert =\text{trace}\left(I  \begin{bmatrix}
T_{M}' &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0&  N
\end{bmatrix}\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sigma_k^{(C)}\cdot 1$
by von Neumann Trace Inequality

*examining the equality conditions:*
$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \vert \lambda_k^{(C)}\vert =\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sigma_k^{(C)}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
T_{M}' &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0& N
\end{bmatrix}$ must be diagonal

Suppose the above is met with equality.
$T':=\left( \begin{bmatrix}
T_{M}' &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0&N
\end{bmatrix} + I\right)$
$\text{trace}\big(T'\big) =\sum_{k=1}^{m} \vert \lambda_k^{(C)}\vert + n$

and the sum of singular values (given by Schatten 1 norm which is subadditive):
$\Big \Vert T'\Big\Vert_{S_1} \leq \left \Vert\begin{bmatrix}
T_{M}' &* \\ 
 \mathbf 0& N
\end{bmatrix}\right\Vert_{S_1} + \left \Vert I\right\Vert_{S_1} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sigma_k^{(C)} + n =\sum_{k=1}^m \vert \lambda_k^{(C)}\vert + n$

i.e. $\Big \Vert T'\Big \Vert_{S_1} \leq \text{trace}\big(T'\big)= \vert\text{trace}\big(T'\big)\big \vert $
But $ \vert\text{trace}\big(T'\big)\big \vert \leq \Big \Vert T'\Big \Vert_{S_1}$
(again by multiplying by $T'$ by identity matrix and applying von Neumann Trace Inequality)
$\implies \text{trace}\big(T'\big)= \Big \Vert T'\Big \Vert_{S_1}$
and since $T'$ is invertible, by our earlier argument it is normal, which implies it is diagonal which implies $C$ is normal.

thus
$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\vert \lambda_k^{(C)}\vert \leq \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sigma_k^{(C)}$
with equality *iff* $C$ is normal

Comment: Thank you! This argument looks really elegant! I will accept your answer later if there are no other proofs posted.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it to make the argument using Polar Decomposition instead of majorization.

Comment: Wow, this argument is amazing as I did not expect we could tackle on this theorem from so many different perspectives! Thank you :)